# Connection Issue on Puppet

Tags: puppet, redhat

When I do puppet agent -t on the agent, I am seeing the following. It happened recently all of a sudden. Few things to mention:
1. The Puppet master and agents are all up and running.
2. The certificate is successfully signed.
Puppet master version 4.3.1
Puppet agent version 3.8.4
OS RedHat, 6 on master, 7 on some agents.

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: Connection refused - connect(2)
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Connection refused - connect(2)
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://vengcjn501.mmm.com/pluginfacts: Connection refused - connect(2)
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': Connection refused - connect(2)
Error: /File[/var/lib/puppet/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://vengcjn501.mmm.com/plugins: Connection refused - connect(2)
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Connection refused - connect(2)
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Comment: If the master is running but agents receive "Connection refused" messages, then it is likely that connections are being blocked at the firewall -- probably on the master's side, but possibly on the agents' side.  Obviously, that might start happening suddenly if firewall configuration was changed.

Answer (score 2):

The `connection refused` message indicates that the master machine is reachable, but its port is not open.

Steps for debugging the issue:

1. On the agent machine, run

   ```
   puppet agent --configprint server
   ```

   This should print a valid FQDN of the master machine.
2. Ping this FQDN on the agent machine. Take note of the IP address being pinged.
3. Check that the master machine owns that address.
4. Use `netstat -tlnp` to ensure that `puppetserver` is listening on port 8140 (all addresses, or the specific IP identified earlier).
5. Make sure that `puppet agent --configprint masterport` on the agent machine returns 8140 (or whatever alternative port used by `puppetserver`).

With the issue you're experiencing, at least one of these steps should fail for you.

Comment: Thank you, I checked all the steps one by one. Everything looks fine other than step 4. When I do netstat -tlnp on my master, I don't see the program(PID) listed. Also when I run the following I get:                puppet resource service puppetserver enable=true
    service { 'puppetserver':
      ensure => 'stopped',
      enable => 'true',
}

Comment: @James well, then the `puppetserver` service is not running after all, it appears.